# can I install cgi of php4 on plesk 12

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, plesk

I have an ubuntu 14.04 server with plesk 12 I know with previous versions of plesk that you could select php4 for a domain is this still the case?

How would I make php4 available to select for a domain?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use 'multiple PHP' Plesk feature. You can use official method from Plesk documentation or third-party Panda PHP from Atomic.

Comment: will we definately be able to run php4?

Comment: Yes. From Plesk documentation - "you can install any PHP version on the server in addition to the supplied one."

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible to run php4 as *CGI* or *Fast CGI*. ([See official documentation for instructions](http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-administrator-guide/72042.htm#o73243))

This is a detailed description how to compile and install PHP 4.4.9 on Debian Wheezy: [How to use PHP 4.4.9 with Apache and ISPConfig 3](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-use-php-4.4.9-fastcgi-with-apache-and-ispconfig-3-debian-wheezy) Then register the new version in Plesk to make it available in "Hosting Settings":

```
/usr/local/psa/bin/php_handler --add -displayname 4.4.9-custom -path /opt/phpfcgi-4.4.9/bin/php -phpini /opt/phpfcgi-4.4.9/lib/php.ini -type fastcgi -id 449
```